# React How to generate a separate stylesheet for a specific component?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

[image]

Here I want to generate a separate stylesheet for Landing component and hopefully for other. Other components will have Hero component too. Can anyone tell me how can I do that?. Is it a good idea?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything with an underscore `_name.scss`, tells your sass compiler that it's a partial scss file. Simply don't use an underscore for single component scss files, for example: `Hero.scss`. Then in your `Hero.js`, you can import the style like so:

```
import './Hero.scss';

<div className="heroContainer">...</div>
```

or, if your webpack has been configured to allow scss module imports, then you could do:

```
import { heroContainer } from './Hero.scss';

<div className={heroContainer}>...</div>
```

If you want to share `heroContainer`'s styles with other stylesheets, simply use the `@extend` in your scss file.

```
clientsContainer {
  @extend .heroContainer;
}
```

The downside to this approach is that you'll have to manually import any partials, like `_vars.scss`, `_mixins.scss`...etc, and any other dependent stylesheets into each new `Example.scss` file.

Ideally, if you're working in a large team, it's better to individualize your scss stylesheets, so that everything is modular (components and their styles can be passed off to someone else, instead of having to send ALL of your stylesheets for ONE component).